# Can I change the playback speed without affecting the pitch with Finch?

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios, finch

Is it possible to change the playback speed of a sound in Finch, but withouth changing the pitch?

Answer (score 1):

No. [Dirac 2](http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac/) works very well.